# Backbone collection not triggering add event on fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been banging my head against a wall for hours on this one....
Looked at many-a-page and I feel like I have my script correct, but my collection is not triggering an add event with add: true passed in the fetch method.  I can bind to the reset event, but the add event doesn't trigger..

Model:

```
test.Models.AppBlock = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        AppID:          null,
        AppName:        null,
        AppDescription: null
    },
    idAttribute: "AppID"
});
```

Collection:

```
test.Collections.AppBlock = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:       test.Models.AppBlock,
    url:         ApiPath + "apps/byuser",

    Loading: false,

    initialize: function () {

    },

    getAppBlocks: function () {
        if (!this.Loading) {
            this.Loading = true;
            this.fetch({
                data: JSON.stringify({
                          Token: test.Session.Token
                      }),
                add:         true,  // OMG WTF ?!?!
                type:        'POST',
                dataType:    'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                cache:       false,
                success:     this.getAppBlocksSuccess,
                error:       this.getAppBlocksError
            });
        }
    },

    parse: function (response) {
        return response.Data;
    },

    getAppBlocksSuccess: function (that, response) {

    },

    getAppBlocksError: function (that, response) {

    }
});
```

View:

```
test.Views.DashboardLatestMain = Backbone.View.extend({
    Loading: null,

    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template(test.Templates.DashboardLatestMain);
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addAppBlock);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $('#latest').prepend(this.template);
        this.Loading = new test.Views.Loading({
            el: '.main'
        });
        this.collection.getAppBlocks();
    },

    addAppBlock: function (appBlockModel) {
        alert(appBlockModel); // no dice....
        var appBlockView = new test.Views.AppBlock({
            model: appBlockModel,
            el: '#latest .main h3',
            After: true
        });
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**edit**

Data returned from api:

```
{
    "Status":["1","OK"],
    "Data":[{"AppID":1,"AppName":"test","AppDescription":"test"},
            {"AppID":2,"AppName":"test","AppDescription":"test"}]
}
```

Comment: Could we have a little bit more information regarding what is returned by you call? Models are added in the collection, but no 'add' event is triggered?

Comment: Are you using BB 1.0? If not, you need to use `update:true` since before 1.0 the default was to reset instead of update, which triggers only a 'reset' event and no 'add' events.

Comment: @MikaelHärsjö I don't see your point. He's fetching data from the server, why would he use set?

Comment: Ah yes,  I will add data as well.. I do get data back successfully and the collection contains the two models.  I think I am using backbone ~.9, but I will try the update: true solution.

Comment: @KennyThompson `this.collection.bind('add', this.addAppBlock);` is that a typo? Your view doesn't belong to any collection, its model does (`this.model.collection`...).

Comment: There is a parent view instantiating this view:
this.Main = new test.Views.DashboardLatestMain({
                collection: new eb.Collections.AppBlock()
            });

Comment: Ok, anyway Paul's solution should work so I won't dig more into it.

Comment: Whenever I change this line: this.collection.bind('add', this.addAppBlock); to this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAppBlock); the addAppBlock is fired.

Comment: @Paul Hoenecke son of a b.  It worked.  Add an answer to this question and I will accept it.  Thanks to all who looked at it as well..  I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Backbone 0.9.9 collection's `fetch` did a `reset` by default, which triggered only the 'reset' event. In 1.0, fetch does an `update` (now called `set`), and triggers 'add', 'remove' and 'change' events by default.

So, either update to 1.0 and your existing code should work.  Or, add `update:true` to your `fetch` call (you don't need `add:true` then because that is the default).

Comment: I went ahead and updated to 1.0, but the addAppBlock method is not getting the model passed to it .. ugh.. I am trying this.collection.on('add', this.addAppBlock) now.  We'll see ..  Thank you again!

Comment: Hmm, don't know why that would be: [http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)

Comment: nevermind.. just ignore me forever.  I wasn't passing the attributes of the model to the template..

Comment: I am using 1.0 and fetch won't trigger `update` event, it will trigger `reset` if add `{reset:true}` to `fetch({reset:true})`, but `fetch({update:true})` won't trigger `update` event.

Also, backbone document don't mention the `update` event in `collection.fetch()` http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: two years later and this still helped me.